# AC line filter polarity

Tags: ac, filter, mains, layout

Currently I working on very simple AC power mains distribution board. I want to use PCB-mounting AC line filter SCHAFFNER FN405-10-02 for EMI reasons. The datasheet provides simplified schematic: [image]

Part has P/P' & N/N' pins marking, but to simplify layout it would be much better for me if i could swap P/P' and N/N' pins. I mean connect Live trace to N-terminal of filter and Neutral trace to P-terminal. Looking at schematic it seems to me it's possible or is it better not to do so?

Comment: Which kind of mains plug your device has?

Comment: MOSFET has correctly answered your question, but IMHO, it would be good to mark your (physical) circuit to indicate that L and N have been swapped, so that someone in the future (even you if you should forget) doesn't make the false assumption that the trace marked N is Neutral and the trace marked L is Line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, marking sounds very reasonable

Answer (score 5):

Yes. They are symmetrical. You can hook up the line leads any way and the load leads any way.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation